# Convert string date to Datetime C#

Tags: c#, datetime

How can I convert `1-2-2016` to Datetime format dd-MMM-yyyy

For Example :

The output of `1-2-2016` should be `1-Feb-2016`

I've tried the following code but it's returing `2-Jan-2016`.

```
 Updated_Value = Convert.ToDateTime(Updated_Value).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

The Data in `Update_Value` variable is coming from database whose datatype is varchar.

Kindly Help me to resolve this .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Works for me, but then Im british with british setup pc

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen i am working on a profile application where employee can edit any field whose column name , current value and previous values are saving so i can not use date datatype

Comment: The reason it is showing `2-Jan-2016` is that you're converting wrong, the formatting is correct. You need to use `DateTime.ParseExact` to specify the exact format of your data in the database.Also, why are you stringly typing your database? If you're storing dates (and times) you should use a Date(Time) type, not varchar.

Comment: Ah, the [inner platform syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DateTime dt;
DateTime.TryParseExact(Updated_Value, "d-M-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);

var newdate = dt.ToString("d-MMM-yyyy");
```

Comment: Can you please tell me the namespace for CultureInfo.InvariantCulture , and one more thing that this code is on aspx page not aspx.cs

Comment: CultureInfo.InvariantCulture is present in System.Globalization

Comment: I've already added this namespace on aspx.cs page but still same problem on aspx page

Comment: For Aspx Page :
1. Import namespace-- <%@ Import Namespace="System.Globalization" %>
2. Write code in code block --   <%
                string Updated_Value = "1-2-2016";
                DateTime dt;
                DateTime.TryParseExact(Updated_Value, "d-M-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
                var newdate = dt.ToString("d-MMM-yyyy");
                Response.Write(newdate);
                %>